# Returns info on Product Page or Cart?

Tags: user-expectation, e-commerce

If a product has additional restrictions for returns, where is the most logical place to present this information?

On the *product page* or within the *cart* when a user adds the specific product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly.

From a *conversion perspective*, a goal might be to ensure customers get as much stuff in the cart as possible, in which case it would make most sense to show any information that might negatively influence their buying decision (like a slightly more complicated returns policy) *after they've committed to adding to cart.* The risk here is that they interpret this as a deceptive move by you, and you lose trust and conversions.

From a user-centric perspective, a goal might be to be as transparent as possible and provide as much information up front, allowing the user to make the most informed possible shopping decision, in which case you should present the info on the product page. The risk here is that, in those borderline conversion cases, you turn the user off the purchase.

It comes down to your ethics as a conversion funnel designer.

Comment: As a customer, I'd definitely want to see any conditions that might make me think twice about buying a product _before_ I put it in the cart. Also, from a practical perspective, it's easier to show per-product conditions on the product page than on the cart page, where several products might have several different sets of conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem here is coming across rude or being too aloof with important info.

Your customers would want you to be transparent and upfront with them and at the same time they will feel like you're being presumptuous if details like *No return policy* is mentioned

I agree with other answer that calls for ethics here but I'd suggest you to mention it as a *T&C*. Have this detail either:

- Mentioned with the product details *like* **This product has a no return/no refund on return policy** or **This product can only be returned in selected post codes** (Amazon does this)
- Mentioned as a pop-up or overlay on "Adding to cart" saying that **NOTE: This product cannot be returned after purchase**